# $routeParams.value is undefined when passing to new controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to pass a value from one controller to another. Using $routeParams as the method for doing this.

My main app references:

```
var app = angular.module('acnApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute'])
```

To pass the value:

```
    //GO TO EDIT
$scope.getOrgDetails = function (orgId) {
    console.log(orgId)
    $location.path('/network_org/edit/' + orgId)
}
```

In my routes.js:

```
        $routeProvider.when('/network_org/edit/:acnId', {
        templateUrl: 'Pages/acn/orgs/network_org_edit.html',
        controller: 'orgUpdateController'
    });
```

On the receiving controller:

```
app.controller('orgUpdateController', ['$scope', '$location', '$routeParams',  function ($scope, $location, $routeParams) {
console.log($routeParams.orgId)}]);
```

When I run this, the console result is "undefined"

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the method "url" rather than "path".
like this :

```
$location.url('/network_org/edit?orgId=' + orgId)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be :

console.log($routeParams.acnId)

instead of orgId because you are defining the id with acnId.

Answer (score 0):

The formal parameter name you defined in your `routes.js` is called `acnId`. So try:

```
console.log($routeParams.acnId);
```

Comment: Thanks for the second pair of eyes DzinX. The route was the problem. I had the wrong reference there and was focusing on what I was passing in the fist controller.